# Can't: draw Ovals and Rectangles together, only individually

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, draw

What I'm trying to do here is generate 5 random ovals and rectangles. If I remove

```
for(MyOval oval : ovals){
                    oval.draw(g);
 }
```

from the first class, it will display 5 random rectangles. If I remove

```
for(MyRectangle rectangle : rectangles){       
                rectangle.draw(g);                         
            }
```

it will display 5 random ovals. If I remove nothing, it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

**DrawPanel Class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel{

    private Random randomNumbers = new Random();
    private MyOval[] ovals;
    private MyRectangle[] rectangles;

    public DrawPanel(){

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        ovals = new MyOval[ 5 + randomNumbers.nextInt(5)];
        rectangles = new MyRectangle [ 5 + randomNumbers.nextInt(5)];

        for (int count = 0; count <ovals.length; count++){
            int x1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
            int y1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
            int x2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
            int y2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);

            Color color = new Color (randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256));

            ovals[count] = new MyOval(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
            rectangles[count] = new MyRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){             

        super.paintComponent(g);                        

        for(MyRectangle rectangle : rectangles){       
            rectangle.draw(g);                         
        }                                              
        for(MyOval oval : ovals){
            oval.draw(g);                              
        }                                                      
    }                                                
}
```

**Main Class**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestDraw {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel);
        application.setSize(300,300);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**MyOval Class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MyOval {

    private int x1;
    private int y1;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;
    private Color myColor;

    public MyOval(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color){

        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        myColor = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(myColor);
        g.drawOval(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

**MyRectangle Class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MyRectangle {

    private int x1;
    private int y1;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;
    private Color myColor;

    public MyRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color){

        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        myColor = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(myColor);
        g.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are allocating two arrays with random length, but then using the length of the first array to iterate through both arrays.
Quote:

```
ovals = new MyOval[ 5 + randomNumbers.nextInt(5)];
rectangles = new MyRectangle [ 5 + randomNumbers.nextInt(5)];

for (int count = 0; count <ovals.length; count++){
    int x1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
    int y1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
    int x2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
    int y2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);

    Color color = new Color (randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256));

    ovals[count] = new MyOval(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
    rectangles[count] = new MyRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
}
```

Solution is to either initialize the elements in each array separately up to their length, or if you intended both arrays to be the same length you could choose one random length before you allocate the arrays. Latter fix would be as shown below:

```
int len = 5 + randomNumbers.nextInt(5);
ovals = new MyOval[ len ];
rectangles = new MyRectangle [ len ];
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing what Farrukh said, I'll be getting ovals and rectangles that are using the same variables, meaning that they will be within each other. Thanks for your help, I found another way to solve my problem, now it gerenates independent ovals and rectangles

```
    ovals = new MyOval[ 5 + randomNumbers.nextInt(5)];
    rectangles = new MyRectangle [ 5 + randomNumbers.nextInt(5)];

for (int count = 0; count <ovals.length; count++){
    int x1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
    int y1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
    int x2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
    int y2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);

    Color color = new Color (randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256));

    ovals[count] = new MyOval(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);           
}

for (int count = 0; count <rectangles.length; count++){
    int x1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
    int y1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
    int x2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
    int y2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);

    Color color = new Color (randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256));

    rectangles[count] = new MyRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
}
```